# GRPC over HTTPS proper client initialization in Go

Tags: go, https, grpc

I'm interfacing from my code certain 3rd party software (particularly chirpstack v4) which provides API via GPRC. When deployed locally, it answers via HTTP and I get the response all right.

However in cluster we have the same server deployed with `HTTPS` (with letsencrypt certificate, not something private) so I'm trying to add corresponding transport layer security settings, but to my surprise I got then

```
rpc error: code = Internal desc = unexpected HTTP status code received from server: 400 (Bad Request); malformed header: missing HTTP content-type
```

I tried adding `SetHeader` to context with `content-type: application/grpc` but this won't change anything so I'm not sure it is really about header (moreover that it works with plain HTTP). So I wonder, perhaps anyone can point me some mistake in initialization of transport layer security?

```
// this is used with plain HTTP
//opts := []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials())}

// this for case of working via HTTPS
opts := []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithTransportCredentials(credentials.NewTLS(&tls.Config{}))}
// also tried NewClientTLSFromCert(x509.SystemCertPool()) - the same

serverAddr := "our-public-address:443"
ctx := context.Background()
conn, err := grpc.Dial(serverAddr, opts...)
if err != nil {
    println("Dial error:", err.Error())
    return
}
cli := api.NewInternalServiceClient(conn)
req := &api.LoginRequest{Email: "admin", Password: "admin"}
resp, err := cli.Login(ctx, req) // error arises here
if err != nil {
    println("login failed", err.Error())
}
```

Thanks in advance for hints and suggestions!

Comment: Have you verified that your server config is valid (using something like [grpcurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) or [bloom](https://github.com/bloomrpc/bloomrpc))? You may also find it helpful to add [`grpc.WithBlock()`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#WithBlock) to the `Dial` (which I guess will show the issue is with establishing a connection rather than the `Login` call).  Please confirm that `our-public-address` refers to the domain name for which the certificate is issued (and not an IP address).

Comment: yep, it is domain name and certificate seems ok (as https web pages are also served over this connection and browser shows no issue), but thanks for hint about trying `grpcurl` - I supposed since web UI is working all right (using `application/grpc-web-text`) everything is fine, but `grpcurl` obviously freezes on connecting, showing nothing with `-vv` option (while works all right with localhost, using `-plaintext` key)... I guess I need to discuss this with our devops as there could be some subtle proxy issue or something like this...